# how to load a custom model trained in tensorflow in AWS DJL

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow

I am trying out the Aws Djl platform. I want to load a custom trained tensorflow model and perform inference. I couldnot find a direct example to in the official github that does this. Can anyone guide me on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is demo project: https://github.com/aws-samples/djl-demo/tree/master/pneumonia-detection

And here is the document about loading tensorflow model: https://github.com/awslabs/djl/blob/master/docs/tensorflow/how_to_import_keras_models_in_DJL.md
and:
https://github.com/awslabs/djl/blob/master/docs/load_model.md